# Find the proportion of 'important' edges among a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, spectral-graph-theory

I met this problem when dealing with a social network problem. It is a subproblem of that. The problem is like that:

We look at a graph $G(V,E)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ set of edges. We define $x \in V$ as an *important* vertex if at least $\frac 1 3\, \delta(x)$ ($\delta(x)$ refers to the degree of $x$) of the vertices in $x$'s neighborhood have degree no more than degree of $x$. We then define an edge as *important* when either one of the two vertices of the edge or both are 'important' vertices. We define the set of *important* edges as $E_1$.

We want to show $|E_1|≥\frac 1 2\,|E|$. I cannot really think out any method. Could anyone provide some suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea how to prove something in graph theory where you know the result is true, the usual first place to start is to try induction on the number of vertices. If you are not 100% sure that the result is true then you should try concocting some examples.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that this is true? Is there a reason for the choice of $\frac13$ and $\frac12$?

Comment: Look at a tree, where each parent node at level $i$ has $i$ children, for $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$ (level $1$ is the root, level $n$ is the leaves). Then the nodes in level $i,i=2,3,\dots,n-2$ are connected to one node of lower degree and $i$ nodes of higher degree. So only the nodes at levels $2$ and $n-1$ are important. How many edges does that account for? (It seems like this should be nearly the worst case scenario).